# How to pull a line that is greater than a number

Tags: bash, scripting

I am trying to write a bash script that will go through a log and show me any lines that the delays are greater than 10... 
A Sample line from the file is

```
Sep 20 00:05:03 hub1 pstfix/smtp[97852]: 3092828wdc81: to=<test@google.com>, relay=google.mail.com[169.182.1.1]:25, delay=3.8, delays=3.3/0/0.21/0.34, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok: message accepted)
```

The part that I am focused on is the "delay=3.8" Please note that the number does contain decimals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F'[=,]' '$6>10' file
```

`-F'[=,]'` tells awk to separate fields wherever `=` or `,` appears.  With the way that your log lines are constructed, that means that the sixth field is the delay time.

`$6>10` tells awk to print any line for which the sixth field is greater than ten.

#### Example

Let's take a sample file with two lines, one with a delay greater than ten and one with a delay less than ten:

```
$ cat file
Sep 20 00:05:03 hub1 pstfix/smtp[97852]: 3092828wdc81: to=<test@google.com>, relay=google.mail.com[169.182.1.1]:25, delay=10.1, delays=3.3/0/0.21/0.34, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok: message accepted)
Sep 20 00:05:03 hub1 pstfix/smtp[97852]: 3092828wdc81: to=<test@google.com>, relay=google.mail.com[169.182.1.1]:25, delay=3.8, delays=3.3/0/0.21/0.34, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok: message accepted)
```

Our command returns the line with the delay greater than 10:

```
$ awk -F'[=,]' '$6>10' file
Sep 20 00:05:03 hub1 pstfix/smtp[97852]: 3092828wdc81: to=<test@google.com>, relay=google.mail.com[169.182.1.1]:25, delay=10.1, delays=3.3/0/0.21/0.34, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 ok: message accepted)
```

Comment: For some reason when I run the command I still see lines where the delays are 0.01 is there a way to eliminate those?

Comment: @KeithBoigegrain Hmm.  That's bad.  So I can figure out what's going on, please show me a line or two where that happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fixed log format, you can use awk like this:

```
cat your_log_file | awk '{split($0, a, "="); split(a[4],b,","); if(b[1] > 10) print $0}'
```

Otherwise, you can use awk regex to match your patterns and do comparisons with the matched pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{match($0,/delay=([^,]+)/,a)} a[1]>10{print $0}' inputfile
```

Here, the value of delay is extracted using `match` function of `gawk` and then used for comparison. So, in this case anything between `delay=` and `,` is extracted using the `regex` mentioned in the `match` function and stored in an array named `a[1]` which is used for comparison.